# Mapping through array with undefined fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a hash table, where obviously some fields are left undefined, because they have not yet been filled.

I also want to display every field of the hash table. However, when I map through the array the function only returns divs for fields that are not undefined, cant figure out how to force map function to display  Empty  for undefined fields.

It looks like that for now:

```js
const displayTable = () => {
  return storage.map(item => {
    if (item == null) {
      return <div>undefined</div>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{item[0][0]}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

With storage being `[undefined, undefined, undefined, Array[1], undefined, Array[1], undefined, undefined, undefined, Array[1]]`

Thus I end up with only three rendered divs.

Comment: There is confusion in the answers stemming from what appears to be a misunderstanding that you didn't actually set the `undefined` values yourself. Instead, it seems the `storage` array is "holey", that is the `undefined` values represent indexes that were never assigned a value. This would be a useful bit of information to include in the question.

Comment: I trusted the console.log stating, that fields are undefined. My beginners knowledge wasnt enough to know that such holes are possible in arrays.

Comment: @MazMat Look at my answer, the explanation is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, `undefined` and *not defined* are not the same things, although trying to access a *non-defined* property of an object will return the value `undefined`. Considering JS also has `null`, this is in my opinion one of the messiest things about JS.

You could solve your issue by filling your array before starting to populate it:

```
storage.fill(null)
```

(Note that `storage.fill(undefined)` would also work! Isn't Javascript wonderful? :p)

Of course, this will only work if the array has a static, known length. If the length is dynamic, you'll have to do something like this:

```
const displayTable = () => {
  const rendered = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
    if (storage[i] == null) {
      rendered.push(<div>undefined</div>);
    } else {
      rendered.push(
        <div>
          <p>{storage[i][0][0]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  return rendered;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The "holey" array is the root of the problem, and this answer is the only one addressing that.

Comment: It might work, I just need to rework my hashing table to fill the array in a proper way that wont interfere with hashing the actual values.

Comment: @MazMat My second example should be a safe bet and work the same way you intended your original code to work, just in a non-functional and much less nice way, regardless of how you work with your `storage` array.

Comment: Made it work, I used regular for loop to iterate through the array after hashing and set all "empty" fields to null and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: You could use `[...storage].map` or `Array.from(storage).map` that will fill any `empty` slot of the array with `undefined`

Comment: @HMR Yeah, I saw your answer. Really cool, didn't know `Array.from()` actually fills empty indices.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is actually populated with `undefined`, you could do:

```
const displayTable = () => {
  return storage.map(item => {
    if(!item) {
      return <div> undefined </div>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{item[0][0]}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

[A fiddle with a working demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/2gkyd68e/1/)

NB. The example uses ternary but is functionally the same as above

But based on an example provided by the OP, this is not the case and the elements they are expecting to be `undefined` are actually empty i.e. there is nothing to invoke the `.map()` predicate on.

Comment: Tried undefined, null, I alsot ried your !item, the behaviour doesnt change.

Comment: something must be weird about your `storage` array then; using it as you listed I get return values

Comment: `null === undefined` is indeed `false`, but OP didn't use strict equality. `null == undefined` is actually `true`.

Comment: Funny enough, your code works while mine doesnt. Would you mind taking look at my example? https://codesandbox.io/s/6l104zmzpz

Comment: @MazMat your hashing function is returning indexes 7,8,9 so you insert directly to those indexes; it seems you aren't inserting indexes 0-6 so they are actually `empty` and not `undefined`

Comment: The fiddle in this answer works because it explicitly populates the array with the value `undefined`. The OP's code is using sparse arrays that has empty indices, which is **not** the same thing as `undefined`. This answer is incorrect. The equality of `null` and `undefined` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm yes I realized this after looking at OPs code; the answer was provided based on the array provided in the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.from or spread operator if you have sparse arrays:

```js
[1,2].concat(new Array(1)).forEach(x=>console.log("Only for 1 and 2:",x));
[1,2].concat([...new Array(1)]).forEach(x=>console.log("1, 2 and undefined:",x));//with spread operator
[1,2].concat(Array.from(new Array(1))).forEach(x=>console.log("1, 2 and undefined:",x));//with Array.from
```

Answer (score 0):

For your actual solution I'd do just like below:

```
const displayTable = () => {
  return storage.map(item => {
    return (
      <div>
        {typeof item !== 'undefined' ? `<p>${item[0][0]}</p>` : 'Undefined'}
        Or just item to check, if it is defined
        {item ? `<p>${item[0][0]}</p>` : 'Undefined'} 
      </div>
    );
  });
```

---

A little bit different, though this might be helpful for others :)

```
const filteredStorage = storage.filter(item => item !== undefined);
const blankStorage = storage.filter(item => item === undefined);
const displayTable = () => {
  return (
   <div>
    <div>Undefined only</div>
    {
      blankStorage.map(item => {
        return <div>undefined</div>
      })
    }
    <div>Defined only</div>
    {
      filteredStorage.map(item => {
        return <div><p>{item[0][0]}</p></div>
      })
    }
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: `.filter()` behaves the same way so this won't work. Also, your return statement isn't even valid JS.

Comment: Not only is this not valid JS, but is proposes rendering values in a different order than that of the `storage` array. Not a helpful solution.